# BigQuery JsonStreamWriter sometimes throw PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have simple table with several required and nullable columns. My java application writes data into it via JsonStreamWriter. Most of time everything is ok, but sometimes it fails with error

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission
> 'TABLES_UPDATE_DATA' denied on resource
> 'projects/project-name/datasets/dataset-name/tables/table-name' (or it
> may not exist).

Data the similar, I am just append it, without update and I have no idea what goes wrong.

```
private Queue<Map<String, Object>> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private JsonStreamWriter streamWriter;

@Autowired
private BigQueryManager manager;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
    WriteStream stream = WriteStream.newBuilder().setType(WriteStream.Type.COMMITTED).build();
    TableName parentTable = TableName.of(project, dataset, table);
    CreateWriteStreamRequest writeStreamRequest = CreateWriteStreamRequest.newBuilder().setParent(parentTable.toString()).setWriteStream(stream).build();
    WriteStream writeStream = manager.getClient().createWriteStream(writeStreamRequest);
    try {
        streamWriter = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(writeStream.getName(), writeStream.getTableSchema(), manager.getClient()).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Unable to initialize stream writer.", ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void flush() {

    try {
        List<Pair<JSONArray, Future>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            JSONArray batch = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
            queue.poll().forEach(record::put);
            batch.put(record);
            tasks.add(new Pair<>(batch, streamWriter.append(batch)));
        }

        List<AppendRowsResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        tasks.forEach(task -> {
            try {
                responses.add((AppendRowsResponse) task.getValue().get());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.debug("Exception while task {} running: {}", task.getKey(), ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        });

        responses.forEach(response -> {
            if (!"".equals(response.getError().getMessage())) {
                log.error(response.getError().getMessage());
            }
        });

    } finally {
        streamWriter.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void addRow(Map<String, Object> row) {
    queue.add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in [v1.20.0](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/releases/tag/v1.20.0). If you’re using a lower version, consider updating the library. I you’re using a higher version you could try constructing the `JsonStreamWriter` builder with BigQuery client being initialized by StreamWriter by default:

```java
streamWriter = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(writeStream.getName(), writeStream.getTableSchema()).build();
```